# (gstreamer) achieving seamless speed changes?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I want to add pitch control to my music player.

since the soundtouch pitch plugin was deprecated (anyways, it bugs out on song's end and has a ~2s delay in applying the speed change) and now we should set the speed by seeking. That skips a lot when changed in quick succession (by an user dragging a slider), and outright skips to the next song often.

I read somewhere that seeking too much can confuse the demuxers, and I believe that is the case, as converting from ogg to wav fixes the skipping-to-next-song issue, but it still sounds bad and has gaps.

how can I implement a proper pitch control with gst?